# Mathematical expressions in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there a way to for example create such a expression in Django templates ?

[image]

Comment: do u want html code to look like that function or python code to implement such function

Comment: HTML code to look like above function.

Comment: You can use the `mathjax` package.

Answer (score 4):

Django templates doesn't have heavy math operations or methods built in.

You can build a template tag that does what you need and then call it from the template. For more information about template tags visit this page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Yes I know that, but the question was how can I create such a expression in django template (html). Is it a way to do that?

Comment: Check the python "math" library it can do all you need. https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#trigonometric-functions

Answer (score 1):

You can use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html) to write mathematical expressions and then [save them as images](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig).

After that you will have to serve them as regular images.

Answer (score 1):

Check this extensive article: "[Math in HTML (and CSS)](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/math/)" comparing different techniques to achieve the representations.

[MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) seems to be a very good solution to create such representation.